# Does embedded fonts in css affect performance per usage?

Tags: css, performance, embedded-fonts

I know there is a performance overhead for loading the font file, but the question is, once it has been downloaded, can I use it freely any number of times on my HTML page? or does it add an overhead every time it is being used?

Comment: Looks like there is no information out there about this. I wouldn't expect any difference between using a downloaded font and using one already on the system. Perhaps you can set up some tests and find out.

Comment: seems like i am about to do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has got to be the complete guide to font-face performance and optimisation: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/

Comment: I read that article before, perhaps I should have said that in the question, but it doesn't come near the subject of the number of times it is being used in a file

Comment: Simple small naive test shows the number of ms it takes to load the font (after caching) does not change... I don't know for sure for before-caching, its hard for me to confirm that, but re-reading the article stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance proves there will be no extra delays, as the font does not block other elements, thus it doesn't rely on the number of elements using it...

Answer (score -1):

A static file will get downloaded only once per page. You can use firebug or chrome/safari's web inspectors to monitor the http requests. If the page is downloading the file twice, you will see it there.

Comment: This does not address the question. OP is asking about increased rendering time for usage of the font in different places in the webpage, NOT anything to do with download time.